# How do I add a body to an HTTP GET request made with Combine in Swift?

Tags: swift, httprequest, combine

I am making an HTTP GET request using Combine and I don't know how to add a body. I know that it is not ok to have a body in a GET request, but I really need to test some things. I am using Xcode 11.4 and iOS 13.4. Stack Overflow doesn’t let me post this question unless i write some more information, but I can’t think of any more pieces of information that you might need for this. Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
//MARK: - Object to retrieve from JSON
struct Doctor: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let patients: [Patients]
}
struct Patients: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let phone: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case name
        case phone
    }
}
class Network {
  enum Error: LocalizedError {
    case invalidResponse
    case addressUnreachable(URL)
    var errorDescription: String? {
      switch self {
      case .invalidResponse:
        return "The server responded with garbage."
      case .addressUnreachable(let url):
        return "\(url.absoluteString) is unreachable."
      }
    }
  }
  let urlRequest = URL(string: URL)!
  let networkQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Networking",
                                   qos: .default,
                                   attributes: .concurrent)
  func downloadPatients() -> AnyPublisher<Doctor, Error> {
    URLSession.shared
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
      .receive(on: networkQueue)
      .map(\.data)
      .decode(type: Doctor.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .mapError { (error) -> Network.Error in
        switch error {
        case is URLError:
          return Error.addressUnreachable(self.urlRequest)
        default:
          return Error.invalidResponse
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
let networkRequest = Network()
 func loadPatients() {
       cancelable = networkRequest.downloadPatients()
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: {
                receiveValue: { doctor in
                    self.localPatients = doctor.patients
                    self.isShowing = false
            }
        )
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: `URLSession` now produces an error when you try to issue a GET request with body data, so it's not possible. Additionally, future HTTP standards will enforce this requirement as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if can be done with dataTaskPublish for a Get.  But You can customize your request with this kind of call:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.httpBody = body
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        // Handle the error here
    }
    guard let data = data else { return }

    let resData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ServerMessage.self, from: data)
}.resume()
```

}

Comment: And what if it was a POST?

Comment: Change the method from "GET" to "POST"
request.httpMethod = "POST"